# High-power battery charging using a 3-phase to DC "benchtop" power supply

Tags: power-supply, three-phase, charging

My team and I are designing a battery pack. I won't go into too much detail about the use-case and I apologise for being vague, but bear with me, I'll provide all the pertinent details.

So, our pack has a constant-current charging capability (based off cell manufacturer specs) that would require 93.6 V (max), 180 A (constant) to reach 80% SOC.

The issue here is that this is 16.8 kW and we're only going to have a three-phase 11 kW socket available to us:

"...will provide a red 3 Phase 16A CEE Power Outlet (IEC 60309, 230-400Vac, +10%, −6%, 5-pole) ..."

This means that we'll only have a potential 93.6 V,117 A available. It'll take 50% longer, but we've accounted for that.

After that point, we can do a bit of constant voltage charging if time allows - holding the pack at 93.6 V and letting the pack taper down its current requirement as it fills over the 80% SOC mark. All good so far I think.

So the next part was working out how/where we are going to get this rather specific power requirement. What can a) convert from three-phase, b) give 93.6 V, 117 A, etc, and c) offer CC and CV modes.

Some searching found [this](https://www.xppower.com/product/NTN21K0-Series?m=NTN21K0-125), basically a very powerful benchtop-style power supply that takes three-phase and does (seemingly) everything we need,  125 V and 150 A max. I can't see it in the spec, but I' sure there'll be some conversion losses etc., but again, another small drop in amperage isn't so bad.

Can you see any reason why this won't perform the function that I've outlined? Are there better options for this use case?

Comment: That's a power supply. Not a battery charger. It will never care about the battery being too empty or too full, or too cold or too hot. So it is lacking all safety mechanisms you would expect from a battery charger. It will also never stop charging the battery when it is full but continues float charge until you disconnect it. You also never reveal what battery chemistry you use.

Comment: Those power supplies are listed as 21kW, and input current is not listed. If the power supply does not control inrush current, it may trip the supply breaker simply powering on. In addition, you will need to actively (software) limit output power to ensure input is <16A. You may also be required (legally) to add a 16A MCB to ensure the plug/socket is not overloaded.

Comment: You would want the BMS to control the power supply, and likely a safety contactor between the battery and power supply in case communications with the power supply are lost or it misbehaves.

Comment: @Justme Ah yes, sorry. We will be charging through the BMS, so over/under voltage/amperage and temps will be monitored. The datasheet for the power supply lists "inrush current limiting: standard ≥700w". MCB/safety contactor suggestions noted (I think they're in the rules anyway). Cells are a very specific LifePO4.

Comment: @SomewhereSomeoneSupportsMonica see above reply :-)

Comment: @jimmyc A BMS is no substitute for a charger that does the job of  battery charging properly. BMS is the last line of protection in case things have already gone horribly wrong and the charger is not doing it's job properly. And that power supply is not a proper charger. You also don't drive a bike without brakes because you use a helmet. Or when skydiving, leave out the main chute because you always have the backup chute.

Comment: @Justme ok, point taken. What would you suggest then? it seems to me that chargers with this specific set of requirements are difficult to find (nay, impossible!)

Comment: @justme Just lookoing at another psu of a similar variety to the first one I linked to.

https://etps.co.uk/products/programmable-power-systems/dc-sources/lab-hp/

Seems like using these to charge batteries is something that theyve thought about:

"Rated at 150% of the nominal output of the model. The decoupling diode is commonly used when the LAB-HP is used to charge battery packs."

It looks to me at the moment like these power supplies are going to be our only option, but that what we need is an intermediary bit of kit added for an extra layer of safety?